# phash breaks when nonetype object apears

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, nonetype, phash

```
import os, cv2, imagehash, PIL



hashList = []

path = "C:\cardscryer\CardScryer-master\pictures"

folderList = os.listdir(path)
print(folderList)

os.chdir(path)

for folder in folderList:

    fileList = os.listdir(folder)

    for file in fileList:

        cardImage = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder, file))

        cropImage = cardImage[15:200, 20:420]

        hash = imagehash.phash(PIL.Image.fromarray(cropImage))

        file = file.replace('.jpg','')

        print(file)

        hashList.append([file[:-4], folder, hash])
```

I think "cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder, file))" is returning as none for some reason because the next assignment gives a nonetype error but it only breaks when all the sub folders are running. Changing it to run on only the sub folder that the error happens in; it runs fine. I'm most baffled by the returns being different on such a minor change.

Comment: I'm a moron, I left a .zip file in a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using backslashes in Windows pathnames, either escape them or use raw strings:

```
path = "C:\\cardscryer\\CardScryer-master\\pictures"
```

or

```
path = r"C:\cardscryer\CardScryer-master\pictures"
```

Comment: You can also write them the Unixy way: `path = "C:/cardscryer/CardScryer-master/pictures"`